# r - how to use a variable in a variable

Tags: r, variables, concatenation

I have a data frame where the row names are words and I can call the first column of that row of data drame using something like

```
>df['rowB',1]
```

i know I can use paste to combine a variable and a string using paste to do something like

```
>paste("the value is ", df['rowB',1], "."]
```

and that will get me an output of the string with the value of the variable.  what if rowname is a variable that equals 'rowB?  I tried to do a first paste to put in the paste above, but the result of the first paste doesn't evaulate to the value, but rather is just a string that says

```
>rowname<-'rowB'
>type<-paste("relatype[\'", rowname, "\',1]", sep="")
'df['rowB',1]'
```

long story short, I want to input a value called 'rowname' as a parameter of a function and have it be evaluated for the value of rowname, so I can then put that value into a string within that same function.

I'm also open to a wholly different solution.  any and all suggestions are welcome.

thanks

Comment: I think you just need to remove the quotation marks around `rowname`, when `rowname` is a variable...

Comment: i made a few edits to clarify what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem might be, not entirely clear from your description, but if rowname is a variable, you don't need anything special, because it will evaluate to it's value anyway. Let

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5)
rownames(mat) <- letters[1:5]
mat
##   [,1] [,2]
##a    1    6
##b    2    7
##c    3    8
##d    4    9
##e    5   10
```

and `rowname <- "b"`, then

```
rowname
##[1] "b"
```

so

```
mat[rowname, 1]
##b 
##2
```

which is the same as `mat["b", 1]`. It only fails, if you use `mat['rowname', 1]`. 
If you want to put this in functions, you can do something like:

```
getElement <- function(mat, row.name, column.index) {

    mat[row.name, column.index]

}


getElement(mat, "b", 1)
##b 
##2 

pasteSenstence <- function(mat, row.name, col.index) {

    paste("The element of row", row.name, "and column", col.index, "is", 
            getElement(mat, row.name, col.index))

}
pasteSentence(mat, "b", 1)
##[1] "The element of row b and column 1 is 2"
```

which also works with `rowname <- "b"`

```
 pasteSentence(mat, rowname, 1)
   ##[1] "The element of row b and column 1 is 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
paste("the value is ", get(df['rowname',1]), "."]
```

If you are not familiar, 'get' in r is similar to 'eval' in python.

```
x=c('a', 'c', 'b')
a=2
x[1]
'a'
get(x[1])
2
```

Comment: this seems close, but isn't exactly right because just using paste without the get function will get the value of the variable df['rowB',1].  i clarified my initial question to make what i want a little more clear.

Comment: @user1714887, just try `paste("the value is ", df[rowname,1], ".")` like @adibender suggested.

Comment: ho-ly cow!  that was correct.  how do i mark @adibender as the correct answer?  i guess i was overcomplicating it by a huge amount.

Comment: Good you figured it out. Sorry I misunderstood your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't understand the question; how is your function different from the following?

```
foo = function(rowname = "Species", d = t(iris)){

  paste("I'm selecting", d[rowname, 1])

}

foo()
# [1] "I'm selecting setosa"
```